# Dow Jones Index Data Warehouse - Correct Dimensions?

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I want to create a "data warehouse" monitoring the stock market's 30 biggest companies (companies from Dow Jones index). My current concept for the model is the following, and the point is to be able to monitor individual stocks and then connect the gold price or oil price and watch how they correlate. I understand that dimensions are supposed to be descriptive, so those gold and oil dimensions are not really ideal, but I can't really put them in the fact table, because the metrics from the fact table are not contained in gold and oil prices. Same goes pretty much for the economy dimension, which monitors different economy indicators.

[Dow Jones DW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNcpt.png)

Does this data warehouse actually make sense, fundamentally? Would it be possible to implement gold/oil (or other) prices to the warehouse for it to make sense?

Comment: The dimension that ties gold, oil, and stocks together is time.  I don't know if you're getting daily closings or minute by minute ticker information.  The economy and mortgage rates change less frequently but still have a time dimension.

Comment: Im getting daily closings. What does that mean, exactly? A dimension cannot be tied to another dimension, so they do have to become fact tables?

Comment: Yes, gold, oil, stocks, economy, and mortgage rates are all fact tables.  Time is the dimension that ties them together.